# How can I find out the row /column of a view inside table layout

Tags: android, tablelayout

Suppose I have a view inside TableLayout, like this:

```
TableLayout tableLayout;
View view = (View)tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.control);
```

How can I find out the view's row/column within the TableLayout?

Answer (score 2):

A view that is within a TableRow should have TableRow.LayoutParams as its LayoutParams.  From that you can get the layout_column.

The row seems to be a bit harder.  I'd expect the TableLayout.LayoutParams (gotten from the TableRow) to have that information, but it doesn't seem to.  You could try using tableLayout.getIndexOfChild(rowView).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such getIndexOfChild(view) in TableLayout class, but a indexOfChild()!

Answer (score 0):

While designing the tablerow in code, you can use setTag() to set it to row number. Later it can be retrieved by tableRow.getTag(). In xml you may use android:tag="2".